# Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\z

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I am bit new in php. I Downloaded a wordpress and installed in my wamp. But the below error encountered.

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'System.php'
(include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\fundwe\...
```

My Wamp is not installed in C drive. Instead it is in D Drive. Please please help me

Comment: `include_path` contains a semicolon (`;`) separated list of include paths. So it's looking in `.` and `C:\php\pear`, which should be fine. Did you check that the file exists and is in the correct location?

Comment: I don't remember Wordpress using system.php, are you sure your Wampp is correctly installed?

Comment: It uses a premium theme for croudfundin. Wamp is installed in D drive

Comment: Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\fundweb\wp-content\themes\funding_press\funding\lib\PayPal\Serializer\Serializer.php on line 54

Comment: This error is showing. I changed Db connection is okay, and i channged field in wp option table, home and site url are localhost/fundweb

Comment: have you checked to see if all the right paths are set in your php.ini?  You will have to restart WAMP once you edit this file

Comment: I installed pear as http://thecancerus.com/installing-pear-and-phpunit-on-wamp-and-windows-7/ this way. but no changes:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WAMPServer, the `include_path` is commented out, so you are getting the default version which is why it is pointing to `include_path='.;C:\php\pear'`

So you could try editing the php.ini file, using the wampserver menus to make sure you edit the correct file `(\wamp\bin\php\{phpVersion}\bin\phpForApache.ini)`

```
wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

And add a proper include path in place of the commented out one in there already

```
include_path=".;d:\wamp\bin\php\{yourPHPVersion}\pear"
```

Although I have an idea this is not related to PEAR at all.

You would probably be better of creating a Virtual Host for the Wordpress site to run in, then it will probably find the file its looking for in the theme folder.

Comment: That is solved now. Now This error occures.. Fatal error: Call to undefined function of_get_option() in D:\wamp\www\fundweb\wp-content\themes\funding_press\header.php on line 50 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0016364760{main}( )..\index.php:0 20.0027368464require( 'D:\wamp\www\fundweb\wp-blog-header.php' )..\index.php:17 32.019643028592require_once( 'D:\wamp\www\fundweb\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )..\wp-blog-header.php:16 42.062043735696include( 'D:\wamp\www\fundweb\wp-content\themes\funding_press\tmp-home.php' )..

Comment: Thanks, i was using wrong php version