# PHP include error when using classes

Tags: php, class, include, wamp

I am running wamp on windows and am trying to use a php include, however I keep getting errors like so:

```
Warning: include(class.DB_Functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ysc\Clients.php

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'class.DB_Functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\ysc\Clients.php

Fatal error: Class 'DB_Functions' not found in C:\wamp\www\ysc\Clients.php
```

Things I have tried:

- Using include, require_once and require
- Set file and folder permissions to everyone
- with and without class. prefix
- manually setting the include path
- hard coding the entire path

Here is one of the files causing the error (on the include statement line)

```
   <?php

    include 'class.DB_Functions.php'; 
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $clients = $db->retrieveClients();

    echo json_encode($clients);

    ?>
```

One of the php files I cannot include

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {
    private $conn;

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'Config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        // return database handler
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

All files are in the same folder where the PHP files that are not classes work fine, but none of the class php files will include.

Comment: this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023454/failed-opening-required-system-php-include-path-c-php-pear-in-d-wamp-w

Comment: How is that file actually called that implements the class `DB_Functions`? That file name (path) is what you have to require or include. Also note that on most systems file names and paths are case sensitive. Only MS-Windows works case insensitive on file systems (whyever).

Comment: @krish thanks but didn't help

Comment: @arkascha the file is called DB_Functions.php and the class is called DB_Functions. I tried different variations on the path but I don't think that is it because non class files work fine.

Comment: You need the line `require_once 'DB_Functions.php';` if the file is located in the same folder as the including script, as you claim.

Comment: @arkascha the files were in a include folder but I moved them while trying to debug. Unfortunately require_once isn't working in the same folder or in another

Comment: If you really use the correct file name spelling (remember: case sensitiveness!) and the files are in the same folder as the working directory of the process, so most likely the folder of the originally requested script and you still get that warning shown above with the same include path, then something is broken in your setup. Sorry.

Comment: i triple checked file names paying close attention to the case but all good. I also think its a wamp thing, but as already mentioned non class files are fine. I also tried copying the class itself into the calling php file and that works. Its only when including classes it doesn't work. In summary, includes and classes work fine by themselves but not when used together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depend on your files location. With your require code, I'm sure that if you put all of your PHP file in the same folder (C:\wamp\www\ysc), that error will not happen

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't work. The weird thing is non class files work fine so I don't think its a path problem

Comment: Ok guys, it was a problem with the file name I just couldn't see it no matter how hard I looked. Came back a few days later and it just stood out.. guess I needed a break.