# I am getting Permission denied error when i use require_once() with ampps

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect

I am using `require_once` to call a function into `index.php` from `Category.class.php` but i am getting this error:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\admin-panel): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\admin-panel\admin-dashboard\Category.class.php on line 22

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\admin-panel\admin-dashboard\Category.class.php on line 22
```

**This is the function i am trying to call:**

```
public function index()
    {
        $db = new DataBase();
         $categories = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `id` DESC;");

        require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "../template/admin/category/index.php"));
    }
```

**And this is the `.htaccess` file :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ admin-panel/index.php [QSA,L]
```

**How can i solve this?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed opening required 'System.php' (include\_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023454/failed-opening-required-system-php-include-path-c-php-pear-in-d-wamp-w)

Comment: No buddy it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, The problem was the syntax error:

I wrote `require_once` like this which is incorrect:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "../template/admin/category/index.php"));
```

When i change it to following code problem was solved:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../template/admin/categories/index.php"));
```